# Injection of Default Typeface

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

**Objective:**

To dynamically theme typeface implicitly (via default) and explicitly (via View code) in Xamarin, through MvvmCross.

**Background:**

Two excellent implementations of Android font customization were identified:

- [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)
- [Calligraphy-Xamarin](https://github.com/mikescandy/Calligraphy-xamarin)

Calligraphy intercepts the inflation of an Android View *(using an Android Context Wrapper)*, and manipulates it to generate the desired effect.

MvvmCross has already been adopted and performs its operations during the inflation of an Android View.

Rather than introducing another technology (Calligraphy-Xamarin), that is platform specific -- I am wondering if there is an eloquent way to implement a cross-platform, dynamic typeface theming engine with MvvmCross.

To inject a cross-platform process into the MvvmCross creation of a View... that will perform implicit and explicit typeface theming.

**Suggestions, ideas, and/or comments, anyone?**

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to replace the MvvmCross binding inflate with a modified version that would call Calligraphy's inflate logic first.  Remember, they are open-source projects, so this is possible at the cost of having to maintain source code forks.

Whatever is registered with MvvmCross's container last wins -- so you simply inject your revised version off MvvmCross's binding inflate last.

Hope this makes sense... if not, please do not hesitate to ask for additional information and/or clarification.

Additional Information...

I no longer have access to that source code, nor a development environment to create a working solution for you.  That said, the following information should be sufficient for a software developer creating Android solutions with Xamarin.

1. Retrieve and add the following project to your solution (Calligraphy)
   https://github.com/mikescandy/Calligraphy-xamarin
   Add a reference to this project from your Android specific project.
2. Retrieve and add the following project to your solution (MvvmCross)
   https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross
   DO NOT add a reference to this project for anywhere.
3. Make a copy of MvvmCross's MvxAndroidBindingContext.cs unit into your Android project (recommend changing namespace) and then modify its...
   public virtual View BindingInflate(int resourceID, ViewGroup viewGroup) so that it will call the CalligraphyFactory.cs OnViewCreated() method after it has created the View using MvvmCross bindings.  CalligraphyFactory::OnViewCreated() is where the font-face gets applied and MvxAndroidBindingContext::BindingInflate() is where the View is to be created with MvvmCross bindings applied.
4. Check out how MvvmCross registered the MvxAndroidBindingContext in its project and then do the same with your implementation, ensuring that it IS LAST, so it will override the original.  If I remember correctly, this would be done in the Setup::CreateApp() method.
5. Make sure you properly initialize Calligraphy (refer to its documentation).

It may take you a while to understand what I have written, and there may be a few mistakes because a lot of time has passed and I don't have the ability to check it, but I am 100% certain that the IDEA will result in the successful inclusion of Calligraphy within Xamarin / MvvmCross, because I certainly did get it to work without any doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Yeah I see what you mean. Have you done this change yourself? Would you be willing to share some code please? Fairly new to MVVMCross, so I'm a bit hesitant about making any changes to it!

Comment: Please refer to updated "Answer".  If you are feeling generous, please also mark it as the "Answer"

Comment: really appreciate the detailed answer! Thank you!! It's not letting me mark it as Answer, since I didn't ask the question. Sorry!! Thanks again

Comment: I don't understand how this works. Might be because things have changed over time, but:

a) Mvvm does not use injection for MvxAndroidBindingContext, it simply does new MvxAndroidBindingContext in an MvxActivity. You can replace that on your own activity. So far there i saw a solution.
b) That CalligraphyFactory is private, thus inaccessible. Still looking for another way around this. But the design of Calligraphy is far from open, lots of privates.

Answer (score 0):

Any luck with this? MvvmCross and Calligraphy-XamariM don't seem to play well togehter. I get "Android.Views.InflateException" . I'm guessing it's because both liberaries try to override the view inflation process.

Comment: Please refer to my revised "Answer"

Answer (score 0):

I released a Nuget package, that is doning basically what WindSpirit said.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Calligraphy/.

The problem with Calligraphy-Xamarin is that `CalligraphyFactory` is not public. You just have to modify the Setup like:

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    protected override MvxAndroidBindingBuilder CreateBindingBuilder()
    {
        return new CalligraphyMvxAndroidBindingBuilder();
    }
}
```